# Yii2, Command class in subfolder

Tags: console, command, yii2

We have folder `/commands/` where we should place `yii\console\Controller` classes after creating such command we can call it in console like `php yii controllerName/action` and it will be called.

But when we create subfolder `/commands/testdata/` and place there our console class with action, on executing `php yii testdata/controllerName/action` nothing happens (i mean error, such controller\action doesn't exist)?

So question is, how to call command from subfolder in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#controller-class-naming

So if we have controller in `/commands/test/UserTestController` with action `actionCreateEmpty` from console we should call it this one `php yii test/user-test/create-empty`

Answer (score -3):

Why not place the controller folder in the root folder? I use a separate folder for my commands. Like so:

```
rootfolder
    Commands
    Controllers
    Views
    Models
    etc..
```

This way you can easily navigate from root (/app/controllers/yourcontroller.php).